# invalid type (list) for variable in logistic regression

Tags: r, rstudio, logistic-regression

I want to try coding like in this link **https://koalaverse.github.io/homlr/notebooks/05-logistic-regression.nb.html** using the **Default** data in **ISLR2** library.

```
# Convert ordered factor columns into factor columns only!
df <- Default %>% mutate_if(is.ordered, factor, ordered = FALSE)
```

I'm trying to run the simple logistic regression. But I got an error when run this code.

```
model1 <- glm(df ~ balance, 
          family = "binomial", data = churn_train)

model2 <- glm(df ~ student["Yes"],
          family = "binomial", data = churn_train)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Instead of df you need to use a dependent variable.

Comment: @jay.sf could you please correct my code?

Comment: You should make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jay.sf I already trying but it still makes error in my code.

Comment: @user19791361 ; you need to use the name of the column that you are trying to predict on the left hand side of the formula  instead of using `df`. So from the link you provide, they use `Attrition`.

Comment: @user20650 thank you for your answer! Now I got an error in **model2**, it says `variable lengths differ (found for 'student["Yes"]')` do you know how to make it work? Because I want to choose based on Student column that having **Yes**

Comment: @user19791361; we really need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see what you are trying to do. But if you are wanting to have a binary predictor in your model, say the column `student`, with the values `"Yes"` and `"not-Yes"` then you can use `glm(your_outcome_variable ~ I(student == "Yes"), family = "binomial", data = churn_train)` (this assumes that your data is called `churn_train` and that it has a binary column  `your_outcome_variable` as your outcome, and a column called `student`, with some `"Yes"` values.